# Angular 8 Internationalization create a huge vendor.js file in --prod environment

Tags: angular, deployment, internationalization, angular8

I have an Angular 8 project which has a decent file size after **ng build --prod** (like 1.3Mb). But I decided to add internationalization to the project, so following this tutorial (https://angular.io/guide/i18n) I created a 8Kb of messages.es.xlf, now when I run **ng build --prod --configuration=es**, I get a file called vendor.js of 6Mb, if I delete **[--configuration=es]** command, then a decent file size is back. I need to add two more messages files, one for **de** and other for **fr**. I'm afraid when these two files are added the web will be like 1 Gigabyte =) . Is there anyway I can reduce the vendor.js ?

I tried this ng commands with none result:

ng build --prod --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --buildOptimizer

ng build --prod -aot -vc -cc -dop --buildOptimizer

Thank you

Comment: any solutions to this problem? I've got the same

Comment: I didn't find any solution, so I start using ngx-translate (https://github.com/ngx-translate/core). It's very lightweight!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your `angular.json`. Probably all you need to do is to copy all optimization options from `production` configuration to your `es` configuration and call `ng build -c es`.

It doesn't look like a good solution because of code duplication, but you can find more details here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10987